# Want to click download csv button using Selenium Python, but button changes class-name when hovered over?

Tags: python, html, selenium, csv, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to save a csv file by clicking the download csv button on a website. However, I noticed the .click() action not doing anything, and I found that the class-name of the button changes from 'export-button is-csv' to 'export-button is-csv hovering.' However, when I try find_element_by_class_name() on the new class name, it returns an error saying it's not there. Here's my code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)

driver.get('https://www.rotowire.com/basketball/injury-report.php')

time.sleep(1)

download_csv=driver.find_element_by_class_name('export-button.is-csv')

download_csv.find_element_by_class_name('export-button.is-csv.hovering').click()
```

Here is the error message I receive:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".export-button is-csv.hovering"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=94.0.4606.71)
```

Was wondering what the specific fix to this is(am using Google Colabs and am new to Selenium).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the table straight from the source then use pandas to convert to dataframe and write to disk:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.rotowire.com/basketball/tables/injury-report.php?team=ALL&pos=ALL'
jsonData = requests.get(url).json()

df = pd.DataFrame(jsonData)
df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Can I ask how you derived the url? Was it through inspect element?

Comment: Yes. Inspect -> Network -> XHR

Comment: How, exactly, did you find that link chitown88? I inspected the HTML and I didn't see anything like this '?team=ALL&pos=ALL'. I see the URL up to the '.php', but I don't see anything in the HTML after the '.php'. Can you describe the steps? Thanks.

Comment: Open up the dev tool panel (shft + ctrl + I). Looks I. The tab Network -> XHR. Find the request in the list. Click it, then in he panel look at Preview. You’ll see he data in json format there. Go to Headers to look find the url for that request.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use

```
button.is-csv
```

`css selector` to click on it.

```
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get('https://www.rotowire.com/basketball/injury-report.php')

time.sleep(1)

download_csv = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.is-csv')
download_csv.click()
```

Comment: added `driver.maximize_window()` to make it open in full screen